# Comparing Alphanumeric Strings From Object Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Posting a revised question from my original, found at at [Sorting Arrays Using Variables Within the Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868901/sorting-arrays-using-variables-within-the-array)
Basically, I cannot seem to find a method for sorting my array based on the `eventCodeString` of my `Event` class. Because the string is alphanumeric (e.g. A123, B321, C222) the conventional Comparator (which I just discovered, thanks to the person in the original post) does not work. The more solutions I come across and try to implement, the more confused I become. Please assist me in understanding the logic of array object comparisons involving strings.

```
package Chapter9;
import Chapter9.Event;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;
public class EventDemo
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        callMotto();
                int x, sortMethod;
                Event[] eventStuff = new Event[8];
                for(x = 0; x < 8; ++x)
                {
                    eventStuff[x] = new Event();
                    eventStuff[x].setEventCodeString();
                    eventStuff[x].setGuests();
                    eventStuff[x].setContactNumber();
                    eventStuff[x].setEventStr();
                }
                //Sorting method start
                do
                {
                    String sorting;

                    sorting = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose sorting method:\n"
                            + "1 to sort by event number\n"
                            + "2 to sort by number of guests\n"
                            + "3 to sort by event type\n"
                            + "Type 99 to exit sorting list");
                    sortMethod = Integer.parseInt(sorting);
                    //Event code sorting start
                    if(sortMethod == 1)
                    {   
                        for(x = 0; x < 8; ++x)
                        {

                        } 
                    }
                    //Event code sorting end
                    if(sortMethod == 2)
                    {
                        for(x = 0; x < 8; ++x)
                        {
                            Arrays.sort(eventStuff, new Comparator<Event>() 
                            {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(Event o1, Event o2) 
                                {
                                    if (o1.getGuests() < o2.getGuests())
                                        return -1;
                                    else if (o1.getGuests() == o2.getGuests())
                                        return 0;
                                    else
                                        return 1;
                                }                                   
                            });
                            eventStuff[x].largeParty();
                        }
                    }
                    //Event type sorting start
                    if(sortMethod == 3)
                    {
                        for(x = 0; x < 8; ++x)
                        {
                            Arrays.sort(eventStuff, new Comparator<Event>() 
                            {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(Event o1, Event o2) 
                                {
                                    if (o1.getEventStr() < o2.getEventStr())
                                        return -1;
                                    else if (o1.getEventStr() == o2.getEventStr())
                                        return 0;
                                    else
                                        return 1;
                                }                                   
                            });
                            eventStuff[x].largeParty();
                        }
                    //Event type sorting end
                //Sorting method end
                    }
                    if(sortMethod == 99)
                        System.exit(0);
                }
                while(sortMethod != 99);
        }   
    public static void callMotto()
    {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "*******************************************************\n"
                        +   "* Carly's Makes The Food That Makes The Party! *\n"
                        +   "*******************************************************");

    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of sort do you want, simple character value sort, or do you want, eg, "X-123" to sort after "X-13"?

Comment: I need the array sorted as follows: assuming the user enters some arbitrary values, say B111, A222, C333, C222, E555, and E111, I would like the output to be A222, B111, C222, C333, E111, E555.

Comment: That's just plain alphanumeric sort, what is the difficulty?  You just have to understand that only "primitives" can be compared with `> < ==`, and for objects you need to use an object-specific `compare` method.  `String` has such a method, named `compareTo`, or you can use `compareToIgnoreCase` if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply because you can't compare `String`s using `==`, you should use `String#equals` instead. Same goes for `<`, `<=`, `!=`, `>` and `>=`.
You could refer to [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for explanations.

That is, you have to replace:

```
Arrays.sort(eventStuff, new Comparator<Event>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Event o1, Event o2) 
    {
        if (o1.getEventStr() < o2.getEventStr())
            return -1;
        else if (o1.getEventStr() == o2.getEventStr()) // this line
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }                                   
});
```

by:

```
Arrays.sort(eventStuff, new Comparator<Event>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final Event o1, final Event o2) {
        return o1.getEventStr().compareTo(o2.getEventStr));
    }                                   
});
```

That `String#compareTo(String)` method comes from the fact that Java `String`s implement `Comparable<String>`, which basically means that they inherently know how to compare themselves.

---

Since I'm at it, I would suggest you to also change the implementation of that `Comparator` on guests numbers:

```
if (o1.getGuests() < o2.getGuests())
    return -1;
else if (o1.getGuests() == o2.getGuests())
    return 0;
else
    return 1;
```

could become:

```
return o1.getGuests() - o2.getGuests;
```

If you think about it, it will indeed:

- return **a negative value** when `o1.getGuests() < o2.getGuests()`
- return **0** when `o1.getGuests() == o2.getGuests()`
- return **a positive value** when `o1.getGuests() > o2.getGuests()`

... which is exactly what we need :)

Comment: Not only have you answered my question, but you cleaned up my code, as well. Thank you for the assistance, I've been at this for 5 hours.